# Front End: How to (properly) achieve this masking effect with css

Tags: html, css, png

I hope this is the right place to post.

I am a a full stack dev with a  focus on the backend for the last few years so I am trying to make sure I am approaching this the right way and that there isn't a newer way to do this then my proposed solution below:

See the attached screen shot. This is the main nav  for a freelance project I took on. It is not a problem on the pages without a hero image, but where there is a hero, I need the image to be masked as shown. If you can't see it, the selected nav item has a triangle underneath it that is attached to a 2px red line that extends the width of the screen. This triangle is made by this same 2px red line and if there is a hero image, the top of the image is masked by this red line and some white space (about 8 pixels) equal to the height of the triangle.

**My Proposed Solution**
I was going to have the designer prepare a graphic for me that is a long png, about 3000 by 8, the only transparency being the part underneath the triangle. When the page loads I was going to load the graphic and position it absolutely underneath the selected nav item with JS, masking the image beneath it.

**My Question** 
Is there a better way to achieve this in 2015 - ie clip paths? Is there a good tutorial on the subject - everything I see is for more elaborate things that don't involve added graphics (ie the red line and white mask at the top.

**The Effect**
[image]

EDIT

This is the js I will use to get the proper offset for my lo-fi (2011ish) solution, observant devs will notice the wordpress generated classes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var x = $("#main-nav .current-menu-item a").offset().left;
        var y = $("#main-nav .current-menu-item a").offset().top;
        var w = $("#main-nav .current-menu-item a").width();
        var cx = (x + w / 2);

        //get target width and set x offset
        tw = $("#masking-selection").width()
        tx = cx - (tw/2)

        //move the masking item
        $("#masking-selection").offset({top: (y+20), left: tx })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question. Below is one way to achieve your need. 
**Note:** Adjust to suit your need.

```css
body {
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

ul  {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  overflow: hidden
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  }

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  position:relative
  }

li.current:after, li.current:before {
  content: '\f0de';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 38px;
  bottom: -35.09px;
 text-align: center;
  left: 44%;
  color: beige;
  
  }

li.current:before {
  color: red;
 font-size: 43px;
 left: 42.4%;
  bottom: -35.5px;
  
  }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
 <li>How </li>
 <li class="current">About us</li>
 <li>Contact us</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like it works on my mac (webkit), will try it tonight - is it cross browser?

Comment: @SleekGeek , i dont see the triangle

Comment: It is a great idea, but the thickness of the arrow borders aren't so great, it must be the font awesome problem. tested on Firefox/Chrome on Mac.

Comment: @sdcr The lines are tinier now. You play around with it until you get the desired result.